# Принцип работы Dictionary

Tags: c#, коллекции

Сейчас встала необходимость создать такой словарь, который бы принимал как ключ мой собственный обьект, а возвращал значение int. Я предполагал, что для этого нужно перегрузить hashcode моего класса (насколько помню, в java работало бы только после этого), но как оказалось, он работает без перегрузки.

```
 obj a = new obj();
 obj b = new obj();
 obj c = new obj();

 Dictionary<obj, int> main = new Dictionary<obj, int>();
 main.Add(a, 1);
 main.Add(b, 2);
 main.Add(c, 3);
```

Вот после этого, подавая как ключ один из этих объектов, я получаю нужное значение, но если это будет копия, то тут наверняка нужно переопределить хеш код. Если переопределю хеш код и equals, то будет работать и с копиями объектов?

Comment: Да, при условии, что вы сделаете это правильно `:)`

Comment: У меня карточные комбинации(и то не все возможное множество), думаю в пределах этого поля возможно сделать вполне нормально) 
В обьекте есть 3 поля типа int, планирую выдавать к примеру 3хзначное число в соответствие)

Comment: Реализовал)

Comment: Отлично! `equals` не забыли?

Comment: Нет, он тоже реализован!)

Comment: @alex91: Теперь всё работает как надо?

Comment: Да, что очень радует. Возращает нужное значение при получении даже копий обьекта.

Answer (score 1):

Похожее обсуждалось на [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/634826/using-an-object-as-a-generic-dictionary-key-in-net)